# MakeFile doesn't recognise environmental variables?

Tags: bash, makefile, environment-variables

Within my .bashrc file I've set a library path:

```
export Foo_Library_Location="$Path"
```

Opening a new terminal and typing echo $foo_Library_Location returns $Path and all is well. Within my make file, under FFLAGS I have placed:

```
-I$(Foo_Library_Location) \
```

However the make file cannot seem to see this? why?

Comment: Your problem is "Opening a new terminal". `export` is only effective for the *current* shell session.

Comment: You mean ? :export Foo_Library_Location=$PATH

Comment: Does your `makefile` possibly redefine `Foo_Library_Location`? If so, you might need to (cautiously!) run `make -e` to allow environment variables to override `makefile` variables...

Answer (score 0):

OP here. So it turns out that I needed and forward slash "/", i.e:

```
-I/$(FRITES_Library_Location)
```

This complies and works fine.